# How to install Lucene 3.0.0 in Ubuntu 8.10

Tags: lucene, ubuntu-8.10

I have downloaded Lucene 3.0.0 and 
when I used the command 
  `java -jar lucene-core-3.0.0.jar` in the directory where Lucene is present

I got this message

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from lucene-core-3.0.0.jar

How do I proceed?

Comment: Lucene is a Java library to be used internally within applications, not an executable JAR. What were you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skaffman is correct. Here's a [minimal Lucene application](http://javatechniques.com/blog/lucene-in-memory-text-search-example/). If you want a self-contained search server, try [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

I am using lucene for information retrieval. you need to set the `classpath` after downloading lucene:

## Setting up the environment in Linux

```
setenv LUCENEDIR /opt/lucene-2.4.1
setenv CLASSPATH .:./lucene-core-2.4.1.jar:
./lucene-demos-2.4.1.jar:./lukemin-0.9.2.jar:
$LUCENEDIR/lucene-core-2.4.1.jar:$LUCENEDIR/lucene-demos-2.4.1.jar:
$LUCENEDIR/lukemin-0.9.2.jar:$CLASSPATH
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that is not an executable jar.  Perhaps you should put all the jars in your classpath, then start with the demo at http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/demo.html .